# Problemas al tomar variables generadas en una función

Tags: python, tkinter

Qué tal ? Estoy generando una aplicación con Tkinter y TkTable para mostrar algunos datos. Logré que la aplicación levante la tabla con los datos, pero de forma estática. Estaba viendo de actualizar la tabla con sus datos cada x segundos utilizando el método after de Tkinter pero me encuentro con el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clock.py", line 94, in <module>
    app = App(window)
  File "clock.py", line 89, in __init__
    actualizar_datos_tabla()
  File "clock.py", line 71, in actualizar_datos_tabla
    print (pami)
NameError: name 'pami' is not defined
```

Entiendo que el error lo tengo en generar_datos(), dado que la función actualizar_datos_tabla() no está tomando las variables generadas con la función anterior.
Qué estoy haciendo mal ?

PD: Aclaro que si yo agrego un print (pami) en generar_datos(), este se imprime lo mas bien.

Les dejo el código:

```
def generar_datos():
    #                -- Generación de datos--

    # Generación de listas individuales

pami = scr.obtencion_lista("Pass", "IP", "dato")
agentes_pami = scr.agentes_en_lista(pami)
indices_agentes_pami = scr.indices_agentes(agentes_pami, pami)


    # Creacion de las colas como obhetos. (Toma valores de las listas generadas anteriormente)

Pami = scr.Cola(pami[0], pami[2], (pami[14])[2:], (pami[15])[2:])
print (Pami.llamadas_actuales)

    #  Creacion de agentes por cola. (toma valores de las listas generadas anteriormente)
    #  Se genera un diccionario por cada cola. El diccionario obtiene el par ["Agente/x" : Objeto]. Donde el objeto contiene todos los datos del agente. (Ver en script.py detalles)

pamidict = dict()
for x in range(len(agentes_pami)):
    agent = agentes_pami[x]
    name = scr.diccionario_agentes[agentes_pami[x]]
    if  pami[(indices_agentes_pami[x]+1)] == "(Not":
        pamidict[agent] = Agente(name, "Ocupado", pami[(indices_agentes_pami[x]+6)] )
    else:
        pamidict[agent] = Agente(name, pami[(indices_agentes_pami[x]+1)], pami[(indices_agentes_pami[x]+4)] )


# --Comienzo de aplicacion--

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        parent.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        parent.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.content = ArrayVar(parent)
        self.table = ttkTable(rows=13,  cols=9,  titlerows=1,
        titlecols=0,    roworigin=0,    colorigin=0,   anchor='w',
        selecttype='cell',   rowstretch='none',  colstretch='unset',
        flashmode='off', ellipsis='...', ipadx=2,    colwidth=30,
        multiline=False, resizeborders='col',   selectmode='browse',
        cursor='arrow', insertwidth=2, variable=self.content,
        insertbackground='white', height='10'
    )

    c_headers = [" ", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]
    for col, word in enumerate(c_headers, start=0):
        index = '0,' + str(col)
        self.table.set('col', index, word)



#  Ingreso de datos en tabla.
    def actualizar_datos_tabla():
        generar_datos()
        print (pami)
        lista = sorted(list(scr.diccionario_agentes.keys()))
        self.table.set('col','1,0', '%s' % (scr.diccionario_agentes[lista[0]]), '%s' % (scr.diccionario_agentes[lista[1]]),
                                    '%s' % (scr.diccionario_agentes[lista[2]]), '%s' % (scr.diccionario_agentes[lista[3]]),
                                    '%s' % (scr.diccionario_agentes[lista[4]]), '%s' % (scr.diccionario_agentes[lista[5]]),
                                    '%s' % (scr.diccionario_agentes[lista[6]]), '%s' % (scr.diccionario_agentes[lista[7]]),
                                    'Llamadas actuales', 'Llamadas concretadas', 'Llamadas abandonadas', 'Total')

        for x, agent in zip(range(1, 9), lista):
            self.table.set('row','%i,1' % (x), "%s" % (getattr(pamidict[agent], "llamadas_recibidas")))
            self.table.set('row', '9,1', '%s' % (Pami.llamadas_actuales))
            self.table.set('row', '10,1', '%s' % (Pami.llamadas_concretadas))
            self.table.set('row', '11,1', '%s' % (Pami.llamadas_abandonadas))
            self.table.set('row', '12,1', '%s' % ((int(Pami.llamadas_abandonadas) + int(Pami.llamadas_concretadas))))
            self.table.set('row', '12,1', '%s' % ((int(Pami.llamadas_abandonadas) + int(Pami.llamadas_concretadas))))

        tk.Tk().after(2000, actualizar_datos_tabla)

    actualizar_datos_tabla()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.geometry("1600x800")
    app = App(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `pami` es una variable local a la función `generar_datos`, no puedes acceder a ella desde fuera de la función. O usas una variable global (mala practica normalmente) o la retornas  `return pami` al final de la función y en . `actualizar_datos_tabla` haces `pami = generar(datos)`. Aparte de esto `actualizar_datos_tabla` tiene que ser un método de instancia como `self.tabla` o no vas a poder acceder a los atributos de instancia como  y no lo es, le falta el parámetro `self`.  ¿De dónde sale `src` por cierto?

Comment: src es otro script que utilizo para conectarme a un servidor y extraer los datos. Cómo es eso de actualizar_datos_tabla ? No termino de entender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error se debe a que `pami` es una variable restringida al ámbito de la función `generar_datos`. La variable es creada cuando se llama a la función y deja de existir cuando esta retorna, **siendo en todo momento inaccesible desde fuera de ella**. En Python una  variable definida dentro de una función es de ámbito local a no ser que indiquemos lo contrario mediante la palabra clave `global`.

Exactamente lo mismo se aplica para `Pami` y `pamidict`, nunca vas a poder acceder a ellas desde fuera de la función y los objetos a los que pertenecen las referencias a las que están asociadas serán destruidos por el recolector de basura en algún momento tras el retorno de la función. Lo que debes hacer es simplemente retornar dichas variables:

```
def generar_datos():
    # resto del código
    return pami, Pami, pamidict

# Al llamarla en actualizar_datos_tabla asignas el retorno a las variables que desees
pami, Pami, pamidict = generar_datos()
```

Si `generar_datos`  solo es usada por la clase `App` puedes considerar hacerla un método estático de la misma.

Aparte de lo anterior tienes otros errores:

- Tu función `actualizar_datos_tabla` debe ser un método de instancia para poder hacer referencia a los atributos de la misma, como es `self.tabla`, dentro de ella. Tiene que tener la instancia de la clase como primer argumento, `self` por convención.
- No debes llamar a `actualizar_datos_tabla` donde la llamas, esto hace que la **llamada se produzca en la definición de la clase**, cuando ejecutas el módulo o lo importas, no cuando instancias, como es de esperar en ese momento ni la instancia ni su atributo `self.tabla` existen. Realiza la llamada tras instanciar o en el inicializador.
- No debes crear una nueva instancia de `tkinter.Tk` (de hecho solo debes tener una instancia de `Tk` por proceso), debes usar el método `after` de una instancia controlada por el mainloop actual, usa el método `after` de la propia instancia de `App` (subclase de `ttk.Frame`).

Con todo esto en cuenta, tu código podría quedar así:

```
class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        parent.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        parent.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.content = ArrayVar(parent)
        self.table = ttkTable(rows=13,  cols=9,  titlerows=1,
            titlecols=0,    roworigin=0,    colorigin=0,   anchor='w',
            selecttype='cell',   rowstretch='none',  colstretch='unset',
            flashmode='off', ellipsis='...', ipadx=2,    colwidth=30,
            multiline=False, resizeborders='col',   selectmode='browse',
            cursor='arrow', insertwidth=2, variable=self.content,
            insertbackground='white', height='10'
            )

        c_headers = [" ", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]
        for col, word in enumerate(c_headers, start=0):
            index = '0,' + str(col)
            self.table.set('col', index, word)

        self.actualizar_datos_tabla()



    #  Ingreso de datos en tabla.
    def actualizar_datos_tabla(self):
        pami, pami_c, pamidict = self.generar_datos()
        print(pami)
        lista = sorted(scr.diccionario_agentes.keys())
        self.table.set('col','1,0',
                       *(str(scr.diccionario_agentes[lista[i]]) for i in range(8)),
                       'Llamadas actuales', 'Llamadas concretadas', 'Llamadas abandonadas', 'Total')

        for x, agent in zip(range(1, 9), lista):
            self.table.set('row','%i,1' % (x), "%s" % (getattr(pamidict[agent], "llamadas_recibidas")))
            self.table.set('row', '9,1', str(pami_c.llamadas_actuales))
            self.table.set('row', '10,1', str(pami_c.llamadas_concretadas))
            self.table.set('row', '11,1', str(pami_c.llamadas_abandonadas))
            self.table.set('row', '12,1', str((int(pami_c.llamadas_abandonadas) + int(pami_c.llamadas_concretadas))))
            self.table.set('row', '12,1', str((int(pami_c.llamadas_abandonadas) + int(pami_c.llamadas_concretadas))))

        self.after(2000, self.actualizar_datos_tabla)


    @staticmethod
    def generar_datos():
        # Generación de listas individuales
        pami = scr.obtencion_lista("Pass", "IP", "dato")
        agentes_pami = scr.agentes_en_lista(pami)
        indices_agentes_pami = scr.indices_agentes(agentes_pami, pami)

        # Creacion de las colas como obhetos. (Toma valores de las listas generadas anteriormente)
        pami_c = scr.Cola(pami[0], pami[2], pami[14][2:], pami[15][2:])

        #  Creacion de agentes por cola. (toma valores de las listas generadas anteriormente)
        #  Se genera un diccionario por cada cola. El diccionario obtiene el par ["Agente/x" : Objeto]. Donde el objeto contiene todos los datos del agente. (Ver en script.py detalles)
        pamidict = dict()
        for x, agent in enumerate(agentes_pami):
            ix_ag_pami = indices_agentes_pami[x]
            name = scr.diccionario_agentes[agent]
            if pami[ix_ag_pami + 1] == "(Not":
                pamidict[agent] = Agente(name, "Ocupado", pami[ix_ag_pami + 6])
            else:
                pamidict[agent] = Agente(name, pami[ix_ag_pami + 1], pami[ix_ag_pami + 4])

        return pami, pami_c, pamidict



if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.geometry("1600x800")
    app = App(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

Dado que faltan muchos datos para poder reproducir el código puede haberse escapado algún error, aunque la idea al menos la muestra.

Comment: Un éxito, me funcionó perfectamente! Donde puedo encontrar mas información sobre @staticmethod ? No termino de entender que función cumple.